# How do you remove Whitespace from two separate webparts

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, page-layout

I have searched online but to no avail. I was hoping someone from here could help. So the issue is I'm trying to remove the white space between 3 webparts on a page. I have created the following CSS which moves all of the webparts up the page.

```
.ms-webpart-titleText.ms-webpart-titleText, .ms-webpart-titleText > a
{
    margin-top: -40px;

    }
```

This moves all 3 webparts up the screen, which eliminates the space from the nav bar and webpart 1 however still does not eliminate the white space between webpart two and three.

All help is appreciated, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you checked any extra div or <p> lie between 2 & 3 webparts?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
     .ms-webpartPage-root {
         border-spacing: 0px !important;
     }
       .ms-webpartzone-cell {
         margin: 0px !important;
     }
 </style>
```

- See more at: http://www.ashokraja.me/tips/How-To-Remove-Extra-Space-Around-the-Web-Part-In-SharePoint-2013#sthash.4JCrsVli.dpuf

Comment: Thank you amit, I have tried this solution but unfortunately it hasn't worked. it still leaves a space between the second and third webpart. I have used the embed source to link to a custom Css page, would this cause an issue?

Comment: Are you using Publishing site?

Comment: Yes they are Amit

Comment: Then You will need to edit/manipulate the page layouts to change how they appear on the rendered page